# iOS: Autolayout causing UIScrollView to not scroll

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, constraints, autolayout

I have set up a `UIScrollView` with which I want to display 12 images (only 8 fit on screen) laid out horizontally. In the following image you can see the problem I'm having (which makes my scroll view not scroll), my constraints and the `UIScrollView` which I have added on storyboard:

[image: Screenshot of storyboard showing constraints]

I have called the following method on `-(void)viewDidLoad`, where I "set up"my scrollview (itemList is my scroll view property and itemNames a array with the images'names):

```
- (void)setupHorizontalScrollView
{
    self.itemList.delegate = self;
    [self.itemList setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

    [self.itemList setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [self.itemList setCanCancelContentTouches:NO];

    self.itemList.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;
    self.itemList.clipsToBounds = NO;
    self.itemList.scrollEnabled = YES;
    self.itemList.pagingEnabled = NO;

    NSInteger tot=0;
    CGFloat cx = 0;
    for (; ; tot++) {
        if (tot==12) {
            break;
        }

        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[self.itemNames objectAtIndex:tot]]];

        CGRect rect = imageView.frame;
        rect.size.height = 40;
        rect.size.width = 40;
        rect.origin.x = cx;
        rect.origin.y = 0;

        imageView.frame = rect;
        [self.itemList addSubview:imageView];
        cx += imageView.frame.size.width;
    }

    [self.itemList setContentSize:CGSizeMake(cx, [self.itemList bounds].size.height)];
}
```

I have added the [self.itemList setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO]; because I saw this suggestion on other posts, but it doesn't work with or without it. The only way it works is if I uncheck use AutoLayout on the storyboard, but that moves the `UIImageView`I use to look as a navigation bar to the bottom of the screen.
I don't know what to do anymore, any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Two Solutions:

1. Create different constraints that can be satisfied simultaneously (you will have to edit). I think the problem is your bottom space and top space constraints are mutually exclusive. please remove one and try again. IF this is difficult for you, try adding another `UIView` to contain the `UIScrollView` to help manage your constraints, it might seem odd at first, but sometimes adding another view to contain your view actually makes it simpler at each level.
2. Turn off Autolayout, and change the autoresize masks of your `UIImageView` to be what you wish.

Comment: I tried removing one of them, but I don't know how to do it. Could you tell me?

Comment: Click the little gear icon on the constraint, and either remove it if it lets you, or change it to be less specific (e.g. variable or auto - so it does not care).

Comment: after this point, autolayout will be more and more important for iOS/Mac UI development and UI programming. the embed-in-view really helped me make scroll view work while still using all the benefits of autolayout.

Answer (score 31):

Try to set your scrollView's Content size int "viewDidLayoutSubviews" method with keeping the autolayouts set.

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
  [self.itemList setContentSize:CGSizeMake(required_width, required_height)];
}
```

Comment: Great it worked out please tell me why we need to add this method.

Comment: thank it worked for me too but whats the difference +1

Answer (score 3):

Insert: `[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(x,y)];` in the following method:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
```