# UIScrollView Not Scrolling?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I have a `UIScrollView` created in interface builder with a bunch of `UITextView` and `UIImageView` objects already added. I have it connected to an `IBOutlet`, and under `-(void)viewDidLoad` I set its content size to `1200x2000`. User interaction Enabled, Multitouch, Scrolling Enabled and shows vertical and horizontal scroll indicators are all set to `YES`. When I launch the app in the iOS simulator, it doesn't scroll. What could possibly be the cause of this behavior?

Comment: post the initialization code?

Comment: There is not any initialization code, I believe that the UIScrollView is automatically initialized by IB. All I did code-wise was to set contentSize property of the scrollView

Comment: override & check the UIScrollView Delegate methods to check whether the UIScrollView is actually getting the touch events or some other view is actually eating up all the events.. for e.g scrollViewWillBeginDragging:

Comment: I know that the UIScrollView is receiving the touch events because it bounces. I can pull the content up, but it bounces back to its original position.

Comment: Can you post the code what actually you are doing in your code.

Comment: This is what I'm doing in code: `_mainScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(1200, 2000);`

Comment: are the views getting laid out to be longer than the default height?

Comment: Did you add constraints to the UIScrollView to have the edges of the scroll view attached to the UIView that it's contained within?

Comment: did u have used AutoLayout? if yes then keep these points in mind.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18006780/ios-autolayout-causing-uiscrollview-to-not-scroll

and also https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1. viewDidLoad is to soon. You must wait until after the layout of the views has taken place. Try setting the contentSize in viewDidAppear.
2. Are you using autolayout? If so, check out the following answer (and forget 1.):
   [UIScrollView doesn't use autolayout constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13499467/uiscrollview-doesnt-use-autolayout-constraints/13548039#13548039).

Comment: I tried the first one, and that didn't help. I checked out the other answer, and wrote this really quick code to implement it: `- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    _mainScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(4000, 4000);
    
    for(int i=0; i<_mainScrollView.subviews.count;i++){
        UIView *newSubview=[_mainScrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
        newSubview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=NO;
        
    }
    [super viewDidLoad];

    
}`

Comment: @Nenad M: Why forget No. 1? The pure auto layout approach seems still to require setting the `contentSize`. Perhaps if you take the mixed approach you don't need that, but I haven't tried that yet.

Comment: @timquinn: And what are the secrets? One secret seems to be [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16029013/426227).

Answer (score 9):

The best way I know how to overcome this problem without resorting to writing code is that it all can be done within a storyboard and here is how:

1. Leave autolayout enabled.
2. Make a generic UIView a subview of the UIScrollView. 2.1)Put all your View components inside this generic UIView.
3. Make a autolayout constraint between a subview and the UIScrollView. You must pin the right and/or bottom of the last subview to the right and/or bottom of the UIScrollView. This is how the UIScrollView knows the content size.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is the only way I have found to work with a UIScrollView in iOS 7 Landscape with Autolayout!!!!!!! :) Thumbs up!

Answer (score 4):

`viewDidLoad` is indeed too soon, but `viewDidAppear:animated` might not be late enough either. The ideal place to set the `contentOffset` is inside `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Autolayout, make sure you put the code to set Content size within

```
viewDidLayoutSubviews
```

Answer (score 3):

I use a custom view on the UIScrollView, for pull to refresh function, and the scroll view is not scrollable. I try set `contentSize` with `AutoLayout`, and try set it by codes too. The scroll view still cannot scroll.

After spending 3 ~ 4 hours, I solve it by `contentInset`. It will tell scroll view to add some extra space for scrolling.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    // Add extra 15pt on the `top` of scrollView.
    //self.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(15, 0, 0, 0)

    // Add extra 2pt on the `bottom` of scrollView, let it be scrollable. And the UI is more beautiful in my case. 
    self.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 2, 0)
}
```

---

Reference docs:

- [Understanding the contentOffset and contentInset properties of the UIScrollView class @blog](http://blog.lucaslouca.com/understanding-the-contentoffset-and-contentinset-properties-of-the-uiscrollview-class/)
- [What's the UIScrollView contentInset property for? @Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1983488/419348)

Answer (score 1):

This is a good walk-through of scroll-views in case anyone forgot after not using them for a while: https://medium.com/@pradeep_chauhan/how-to-configure-a-uiscrollview-with-auto-layout-in-interface-builder-218dcb4022d7.

Basically, make sure you have view -> scrollview -> view, like so:
[image]
then,
1. Set scroll view constraint (top, bottom, leading and trailing) to (0,0,0,0).
2. Set inner view constraint (top, bottom, leading and trailing) to (0,0,0,0).
3. Set inner view to have equal width and equal height with parent view.
4. Select height constraint of inner view and set priority to low (250).