# UIScrollView does not scroll?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I am using storyboard. In one of the my UIViewController, i have UIScrollView.

But UIScrollView does not scroll. I am setting the content size of the UIScrollView at viewDidLoad method. Unfortunately, it does not work.

How can i solve this?

Here is my code;

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

   [mainScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(0, (bankNameField.frame.origin.y+280))];
}
```

Comment: Can u please show your code over here?

Comment: Plz provide code of what you are doing?

Comment: show your code, what are the contents are included ...

Comment: since i am using storyboard, there is no code. just my setcontentsize line, do you want me to put something else?

Comment: put the code using which you are doing something with scrollView. or you are displaying something in scrollview.

Comment: where you set `bankNameField` in scrollView??

Comment: in an interface builder

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using autolayout, you don't have to set the content size. Try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20662842/ios-horizontal-uiscrollbar-with-autolayout/20663090#20663090).

**Edit:**

If you are adding the subviews in storyboard you can add the constraints right there, just be careful to have at least one constraint tied to each side of the Scroll View

Comment: how to add constraints?

Comment: ctrl+drag, like you would add an IBAction. But remove first the existing constraints, to have only the ones defined by you. If you have dev account, apple has some WWDC videos about auto layout. You can learn much from there.