# iOS removing an object from superview demolishes auto layout and disables scrollview

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, uibutton, autolayout

I have a button that's programmatically laid out and positioned with manually set constraints. I then try to remove the button from the view by calling `removeFromSuperview`. Removing the button causes a collection view subview positioned below the button to lose it's position in the `scrollview` and align itself to the top of the `superview` behind all the other objects. I expected the collection view to simply move up to where the button was once the button and it's constraints had been removed from the view. **What am I missing?**

**Button creation:**

```
aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[aButton addTarget:self
            action:@selector(buttonPressed:)
  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[aButton setTitle:@"Expand" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[aButton setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[self addSubview:aButton];
```

**Button removal:**

```
- (void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender{
    NSLog(@"Pressed");
    [aButton removeFromSuperview];
}
```

**Vertical positioning (detailOfLocation is the collection view):**

```
[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[locationImageContainer(213)][locationTitle][locationDescription][aButton][detailOfLocation]|"
                                                                     options:0
                                                                     metrics:0
                                                                       views:viewArranging]];
```

**[Edit]**

The removal of the button also seems to disable the scrolling ability of the UIScrollView that is the superview where everything is placed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably have some insufficient constraints after removing the button, so maybe you should compensate those. For example, you might want to add a constraint between `locationDescription` and `detailOfLocation` since their vertical position becomes ambiguous after removing the button. The scrollview scrolling is also related probably to the constraints. Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20662842/ios-horizontal-uiscrollbar-with-autolayout/20663090#20663090)

Comment: Yup! I had the button apply an updated constraint right after it removed itself from the view and now everything displays as expected.