# scrollView doesn't work even though contentSize is larger than frame and subview is added before setting content size

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{

[super viewDidLoad];




self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sprites_0001_Rectangle-1.png"]  forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];



self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;

UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sprites_0000s_0008_1st-Page.png"];
imageView.image = image;


//imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.view = imageView;



if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {

     //Write the code to set up view for iPad

   }else{

    UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
    scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-40-[scrollView(==240)]"
                                                                      options:0
                                                                      metrics:nil
                                                                        views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(scrollView)]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-50-[scrollView(==468)]"
                                                                      options:0
                                                                      metrics:nil
                                                                        views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(scrollView)]];

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ParentsMock.png"]];
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [scrollView addSubview:imageView];



    [scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[imageView(==1000)]|"
                                                                       options:0
                                                                       metrics:0
                                                                         views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(imageView)]];
    [scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[imageView(==2000)]|"
                                                                       options:0
                                                                       metrics:0
                                                                         views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(imageView)]];

    }
```

This is my attempt to create `UIScrollView` programmatically however I couldn't make the `scrollView` work even though I set the `contentSize` after adding the subview into the `scrollView`.

[image: How it looks like]

As you can see in this picture, I use UINavigationController to wrap a UIViewControllar and set UIImageView as its view. the I created a scrollView and add it on top of the view. then I create another imageView1 and insert it into the scrollView.

**please note that the view of the entire view controller is an imageView which is different from the imageView i insert into the scrollView.**

Comment: You use autolayout, remove `initWithFrame`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the answer. It seems that I need to enable userInteraction on UIImageView. Remember when I use UIImageView as the view of the view controller. Therefore default value for userInteractionEnabled Property of UIImageView is NO. It ACCEPTS NO touches at all. We need we enable it like this

```
imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

PROBLEM Solved.

Answer (score 1):

You should set your content size using constraints, ton by setting it directly. It does not scroll because you don't have constraints to the left, top, right or bottom of your scroll view content. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20662842/ios-horizontal-uiscrollbar-with-autolayout/20663090#20663090)

**Edit:**

Try adding this:

```
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:
                                                         @"|[imageView(==1000)]|"
                                                        options:0
                                                        metrics:0
                                               views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(imageView)]];
    [scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:
                                                         @"V:|[imageView(==2000)]|"
                                                        options:0
                                                        metrics:0
                                               views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(imageView)]];
```

and remove the code where you are setting the content size.

**Edit:**

Replace your entire code with this:

```
        UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
        scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

        [self.view addSubview:scrollView];
        [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-40-[scrollView(==240)]"
                                                                          options:0
                                                                          metrics:nil
                                                                            views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(scrollView)]];
        [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-50-[scrollView(==468)]"
                                                                          options:0
                                                                          metrics:nil
                                                                            views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(scrollView)]];

        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ParentsMock.png"]];
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        [scrollView addSubview:imageView];



        [scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[imageView(==1000)]|"
                                                                           options:0
                                                                           metrics:0
                                                                             views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(imageView)]];
        [scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[imageView(==2000)]|"
                                                                           options:0
                                                                           metrics:0
                                                                             views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(imageView)]];
```

Comment: i tried still doesn't work. I updated the code please check it.

Comment: Ok i already replace all my code with yours still not working, i update the code in viewDidLoad up there.

Comment: I just tried the code I posted and it works for me so you must be doing something else wrong

Comment: are you using the code I used up there cuz I've just updated the code to match yours in viewDidLoad. I set UIImageView as the view up there.   self.view = imageView;

Comment: I only pasted the code I posted into one of my `viewDidLoad` methods, haven't tried your entire `viewDidLoad`. Maybe you should try first leaving only `[super viewDidLoad]` and my code there to see if it works

Answer (score 0):

The only way I have been successful in creating UIScrollViews is to use Autolayout. This is the simplest and most effective way I know. For this you will need to remove the

```
initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 100, 240, 168)];
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem that you are having? Does it not scroll at all?

Comment: yes not scroll at all it feels like a plain view. No scrolling bar at all when i try to scroll it

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
NSDictionary *layoutDic = ....
```

With:

```
NSDictionary *layoutDic = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(scrollView);
```

Edit: I use your code, and it works, I can scroll, I do in viewDidLoad

```
UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 100, 240, 168)];

UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"purple_button.png"]];
[scrollView addSubview:imageView];
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(1000, 2000);
scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
NSDictionary *layoutDic = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(scrollView);
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];
NSArray *scrollViewConstraintWidth = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-40-[scrollView(==240)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:layoutDic];
NSArray *scrollViewConstraintHeight = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-50-[scrollView(==468)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:layoutDic];
[self.view addConstraints:scrollViewConstraintHeight];
[self.view addConstraints:scrollViewConstraintWidth];
```

Comment: how about my other key value pairs in the view?

Comment: I don't know key-value you declare right or not. But when I use auto layout, I use `NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings` like Apple recommends. If you have scrollView and label NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(scrollView,label), and set constraints.

Answer (score 0):

in properties under Show the file inspector uncheck Use Auto Layout

Comment: i created this view programmatically.

Comment: there is only .h and .m file no xib file or storyboard.

Comment: Actually this issue is relater with Auto Layout, you have to turn off auto layout programatically.

Comment: Actually I need auto layout!

Answer (score 0):

Add the delegate to self like this:

```
 UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]init];

scrollView.delegate=self;

 UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ParentsMock.png"]];
 [scrollView addSubview:imageView];
```

Comment: scroll view content size must be greater then scroll view frame then it will be scrollable