# Autolayout issues with ScrollView width (wrong value)

Tags: storyboard, swift

i am struggling with autolayout in xCode 6 Storyboard.

The Problem: All elements have the correct size an position. But my ViewController get the wrong width of the scrollView. On iPad I get 300 (which is for Phone) instead of 500.

What's wrong

```
func setupView() {
    let pagesScrollViewSize :CGSize = self.scrollView.frame.size;

    var vc : IntroPageViewController!
    var vc2 : IntroPageViewController!

    if(isPad()) {
        println("is Pad. width: \(self.scrollView)")  // shows width: 300. Has to be 500
        vc = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(AppConfiguration.MainStoryboard.ViewControllerIdentifiers.InfoPage1_Pad) as IntroPageViewController
        vc2 = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(AppConfiguration.MainStoryboard.ViewControllerIdentifiers.InfoPage2_Pad) as IntroPageViewController
    } else {
        println("is phone")
        vc = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(AppConfiguration.MainStoryboard.ViewControllerIdentifiers.InfoPage1_Phone) as IntroPageViewController
        vc2 = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(AppConfiguration.MainStoryboard.ViewControllerIdentifiers.InfoPage2_Phone) as IntroPageViewController

    }

    self.scrollView.addSubview(vc.view)
    vc2.view.setX(self.scrollView.width())
    self.scrollView.addSubview(vc2.view)

    // close button listener
    let tap:UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "closeIntro:")
    vc2.closeButton.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(pagesScrollViewSize.width * 2, pagesScrollViewSize.height)

}
```

[image: iPad View]

[image: iPhone View]

Comment: One (maybe) unrelated observation: you shouldn't set the `contentSize` of your scroll view explicitly. You should do this by adding constraints for its subviews. See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23947094/scrollview-doesnt-work-even-though-contentsize-is-larger-than-frame-and-subview/23947444#23947444).

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer:
You have to run this code in the viewDidLayoutSubviews() method.

[iOS AutoLayout - get frame size width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12527191/ios-autolayout-get-frame-size-width/14147303#14147303)