# Pure autolayout with a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview, autolayout

I'm trying to get a `UIScrollView` working with autolayout positioning and sizing. I'm following the guidelines for a "Pure Auto Layout Approach" in [this documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html), but I'm having a hard time getting it to work.

My hierarchy looks like this:

`UICollectionViewCell -> UIView -> UIScrollView -> UIView`.

Everything is positioned with autolayout constraints, including the `UIScrollView` (which is positioned relative to it's direct parent `UIView`). The `UICollectionViewCell` does have a fixed size eventually, as it's set by `collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath`, but I don't think that's relevant this this issue.

The issue I'm having is that the content of the last `UIView` (the child of the `UIScrollView`) isn't showing up. If I manually give it a frame size, it does show, but I really want to use autolayout.

There's a line in that documentation article that I don't quite understand:

`Position and size your scroll view with constraints external to the scroll view.`

Does this indicate that I can use autolayout to position and size the scroll view within it's parent, or does the scrollview *have* to have a fixed frame?

Comment: Take a look at my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23947094/scrollview-doesnt-work-even-though-contentsize-is-larger-than-frame-and-subview/23947444#23947444)

Comment: @Levi So it looks like you *are* still setting fixed width and height constraints on the view inside the scrollview (although you do it with autolayout constraints). Is there any way to do it without calculating a fixed size for the content?

Comment: The size of the content does not have to be fixed, you just have to specify top, bottom, left and right constraints from the subviews to the scrollview, this is how the scrollview calculates its content size when using auto layout. Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20662842/ios-horizontal-uiscrollbar-with-autolayout/20663090#20663090) too, maybe it is more appropriate for your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Autolayout with UIScrollView may seem too complicated at first. Conisder following two things:

1) UIScrollView externally behaves like any another UIView. This means, you can set any position/size to it with auto layout constraints. No differences from UIView.

2) UIScrollView internally CAN (but not should) calculate it's content size basing on given auto layout constraints inside it. For this behavior you should give one odd explicit horizontal & vertical  constraint for it.

Say: you has UIView child inside UIView parent. You pin left, top, bottom, right from child to parent. There are ENOUGH constraints, to calculate child's position and size - it's ok.
Now, you do have UIView child inside your UIScollView parent - and the same set of constraints. There are NOT ENOUGH constraints to calculate scroll view's content size. For calculating scroll view's content size, you should set for example equal widths & equal heights constraints for your child to your UIScrollView parent.

Despite you've given not enough info to find your problem out, i think, you most likely didn't set constraints to size/position your UIScrollView inside it's parent. After that - you probably didn't set one more explicit constraint in each direction inside the scroll view to calculate its content size.

I strongly suggest to read ray wenderlich's iOS 6 by tutorials autoalayout parts - you will understand HOW and WHY auto layout works so.

Comment: Let me see if I understand you: I need to provide an *explicit* size for the UIView inside the UIScrollView. Is that right? It seems to me based on the documentation that you *shouldn't* have to give size to the view inside the scroll view (or at least, you shouldn't have to provide a content size).

Comment: Explicit size isn't like 200px obligatory. You can set something like "equal to scroll view's width, equal to scroll view's height" (which is used for scrolling for example, set of UIImageView's inside the scroll view), or give some percentage. But technically you are right - for calculating content size you should set some EXPLICIT rule to calculate the size. Theoretically this can be an equality rule (like in my example) or some other setup which allows autolayout system to calculate size

Comment: What if I have no way of knowing what the size of the content of the single UIView inside the scroll view will be? (I'm doing custom drawing with drawRect, so it's not just a matter of giving subviews inside the UIView some sizes.)

Comment: To clarify: I can easily set a width/height for the scrollview. But that does nothing unless I also set a width/height for the view inside the scroll view. But since I have no idea until after layout what the width/height of the child view is, I can't set it to any sensible value!

Comment: Never mind. I just spent the time to figure out a way to calculate the correct child content size.

Comment: > I have no way of knowing what the size of the content of the single UIView inside the scroll view will be.   You think of it in incorrect way. I'm almost sure you can calculate correct size of child view.

Answer (score 0):

Say you are working with a nib whose size is 568 in height, and the inner view is 650 high.

First make the scroll view the same height as the inner view.  Then pin the four sides of the scroll view to its container view, however you will notice that the bottom constraint is a negative number - make this 0.

[image]

You will notice that there is a problem with the bottom constraint:

[image]

Don't worry, that will be fixed in the next step.

Now pin all four sides of the inner view to that of the scroll view, as well as its width and height:

[image]

You will now notice that the previous error has disappeared, and when you run the project, you should now be able to scroll to see the content out of view.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "then pin the width and height of the view inside the scroll view." Isn't that exactly the same as "pin all sides of the view inside of the scroll view to the edges of the scroll view"?

Comment: I have updated my answer with screenshots which will hopefully help. Pinning the width and height is not the same as pinning the edges. Pinning the width and height of the inner view is what gives the scrollview its content size.

Comment: ah, I see my confusion now. I'm doing this entirely programmatically - I don't have any experience with the IB. If I add a constraint like this: `[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[innerView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];`, is that pinning the width or pinning to the horizontal edges?

Comment: I don't have too much experience with the visual format, however I believe you are correct as H means horizontal, so you would also need similar with V for vertical.